# Laravel Voyager Image upload failed and getting error message "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException Reading Exif data is not supported"

Tags: php, laravel, image-upload, intervention, voyager

I just start learning laravel voyager. I installed laravel voyager in my new laravel project and everything works fine but when I try to post with image and I am getting an error message like this - **"Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException
Reading Exif data is not supported by this PHP installation."**
I have tried changing APP_URL, clear config, clear cache, and many more. but I can't solve this issue. if anyone knows the solution please help me. Sorry for my bad English(not my mother tongue). thanks!
[image]

Comment: are you sure the exif extension  is installed and uncommented in your machine?

Comment: I just uncomment the exif extension. Now it works. thanks for suggestion bro.

Comment: @Student from where did you uncomment it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in windows local server please enable exif extension in php.ini
or you can install php-exif

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-exif
```

[image: 1]